# How do you prevent Visual studio code analysis from running on a dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

A project contains a runtime callable wrapper generated from a COM dll. I have Code analysis rules enabled on the project. The problem is that VS runs code analysis on the RCW dll too!

How do I stop VS from running code analysis only for that dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't looking hard enough.

To disable code analysis on generated code, open the project properties page, go to the Code Analysis tab and check the **Suppress results from generated code (managed only)** check box.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385906(v=vs.90).aspx)